# Linux: I want to fetch the top 10 records of the column3. The column has some missing data. I have sorted the file

Tags: linux, sorting

I am not sure how to ignore the missing data here.

My `;` separated file looks like (*writing it with spaces so that it is readable*):

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
12    a     ?     ?     ?
1     b     ?     ?     ?
45    c     7.22  6.09  2.2
11    d     7.0   3.89  9.7
26    e     6.24  8.2  5.9
and so on....
```

I want to fetch the records with maximum values of column3

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
45    c     7.22  6.09  2.2
11    d     7.0   3.89  9.7
26    e     6.24  8.2  5.9
```

I sorted the file on column3 in reverse order. Not sure how to proceed further.

```
sort -t';' -k3 -r original.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: @Allan: Why would this question need an `awk` tag when OP never mentions to try seeking an alternate tool than `sort`?

Comment: @Inian: Yeah you are right sorry for that. I have also provided an `awk` alternative

Answer (score 3):

Something great about the command line is that you can easily use the best tool for the proper application, either chaining output with pipes `|` or by creating temporary files like `newfile.txt`.

In this case, using `sort` is the apt choice for sorting your data. Once it's sorted, you can use a separate tool that's very efficient at parsing data, `awk`.

Starting from your sorted `newfile.txt`, this `awk` operation will only print a line with 5 fields (assuming your missing data is actually missing and there are no empty separators, e.g. your line looks like `45;c;` rather than `45;c;;;`)

```
awk -F';' 'NF == 5 { print }' newfile.txt
```

However, in the case that the empty fields are delimited (e.g. `45;c;;;`), and assuming that only columns 3 through 5 may have missing data, this will handle it:

```
awk -F';' 'NF == 5 && $3 && $4 && $5 { print }' newfile.txt
```

Note that since the default behavior of `awk` is to print, the above `{ print }` is actually unnecessary, but included pedagogically.

Thus, from start to finish, you can get your desired result with,

```
sort -t ';' -rk3 original.txt | awk 'NF==5 && $3 && $4 && $5' > result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
$ head -1 fileToSort; (sort -k3 -n -r <(tail -n +2 fileToSort) | head)
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
45    c     7.22  6.09  2.2
11    d     7.0   3.89  9.7
26    e     6.24  8.2  5.9
1     b     ?     ?     ?
12    a     ?     ?     ?
```

where `fileToSort` is

```
 cat fileToSort 
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
12    a     ?     ?     ?
1     b     ?     ?     ?
45    c     7.22  6.09  2.2
11    d     7.0   3.89  9.7
26    e     6.24  8.2  5.9
```

**Explanations:**

- Use `-t';'` if your field separator is `;`
- `<(tail -n +2 fileToSort)` will exclude the header of the input file
- You then sort it via the 3rd key in reverse and numeric mode using `-n`
- `head` will limit the output at the first 10 records
- `head -1 fileToSort;` will print the header line before printing the top 10 records

If you need an `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR==1;NF == 5 && $3~/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+$/ && $4~/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+$/ && $5~/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+$/{buff[$3]=$0}END{n=asorti(buff,out); for (i = n; i >= 1; i--){print buff[out[i]]}}' fileToSort 
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
45    c     7.22  6.09  2.2
11    d     7.0   3.89  9.7
26    e     6.24  8.2  5.9
```

You might need to add `-F';'` just after the `awk` command if your file does have `;` instead of spaces. Your command will become: `awk -F';' ...`

- `NR==1;` print the first line
- `NF == 5 && $3~/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+$/ && $4~/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+$/ && $5~/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+$/` check that you have 5 fields and that the values of the 3 last columns are numerical
- `{buff[$3]=$0}` save each line in a buffer indexed by the `col3` value
- `END{n=asorti(buff,out); for (i = n; i >= 1; i--){print buff[out[i]]}}` at the end of the processing just order the array depending on the value of the index and print it in the reverse order.